# Chrome Extension disabled when ExtensionInstallForceList is set?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My company developed a custom extension. We installed it by clicking `Load unpacked extension` and selected the extension folder. This is the manifest.json for the extension:

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"Wells media extension",
    "version":"0.1",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":[
                ....
            ],
            "js":[
                "jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
                "content.js"
            ],
            "run_at":"document_start"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what my chrome://extensions tab look like:
[image]

## Problem: This extension is disabled as soon as we set ExtensionInstallForceList.

[image]

This is what `chrome://extensions` looks like:

[image]

This is what `chrome://policy` looks like:

[image]

## Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you loading the extension unpacked, or as a crx from the chrome web store? It looks like you're trying to do both.

Comment: @JoshLee I am loading the extension unpacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExtensionInstallForceList is for packed extensions, not unpacked extensions.

Since the format is an extension id followed by an update URL, presumably you must actually make the extension available at that update URL.

Comment: FYI I packed the extension, turn on ExtensionInstallForceList, and I am still seeing my packed extension disabled. "Unsupported Extensions Disabled
To make Chrome safer, we disabled the following extension that isn’t listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge"